# How to display the values of a class?

Tags: c++, class, object, floating-point, display

I am almost new in c++. I have created a class of a student. First of all, when i returned the media of the marks, it isn't a float value. For example: if I enter 5 and 10, it returns 7 instead of 7.5.

Secondly, when I want to display the name and media with the function disp(), it doesn't work.

Could anyone help a bit?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student{
    public:
        string name;
        int mark1, mark2;

        float calc_media(){ 
            float media = (mark1 + mark2)/2; 

            return media; 

        }
        void disp(){
            cout << "Student:" << name << endl;
            cout << "media:"<< calc_media() << endl;
        }

};



int main (){
    student peter;

    cout <<"name:" ;
    cin>>peter.name;
    cout <<"mark1:" ;
    cin>>peter.mark1;
    cout <<"mark2:" ;
    cin>>peter.mark2;
    cout <<"ALL:" << peter.disp();




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings that is shows a lot of error and are no related to the sintaxis, it's about the logic.

Comment: If there are problems, do you think it might be helpful to tell us what they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression:

```
(mark1 + mark2) / 2;
```

you are doing integer division, since both the variables and the literal are `int` types. You could simply do:

```
(mark1 + mark2) / 2.0;
```

instead, to get floating point division.

To get `disp` to work, note that it doesn't return anything, so you need to simply call it like this:

```
peter.disp();
```

and not pass the result of this function to `cout`.

Alternatively, instead of `disp`, you can overload the `operator<<` like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(student const &s, std::ostream &out)
{
  out << "Student:" << name << endl;
  out << "media:"<< calc_media() << endl;
  return out;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
cout << peter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what you are doing is called integer division, both variables `mark1` and `mark2` are integers and so is `2` thus, it will provide you an integer.

```
float calc_media(){ 
            float media = (mark1 + mark2)/2;
```

Try replacing `2` with `2.0` to achieve floating point division.

```
float media = (mark1 + mark2)/2.0;
```

And as your `disp` function is not returning something you need not to `cout` it. You can do this,

```
cout <<"ALL:";
peter.disp();
```